# Show linearity of this map, if and only if statement

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $Γ_f = \{(s, t)\mid t = f(s)\} \subset S \times T$

Suppose that $U$ and $V$ are vector spaces and $f ∈ V^U$
(i.e. f is a map of underlying sets which is not necessarily linear).

how do you show that $f$ is linear if and only if $Γ_f$ is a linear subspace of $U ×
V$?

Comment: Always start with the definitions. What does it mean to be linear? What does it mean to be a subspace of $U\times V$?

Answer (score 0):

Take a basis $\{u_i\}$ of $U$, and a basis $\{v_i\}$ of $V$ (not necessarily of the same size of course). Then note you have the canonical basis of $U \times V$ consisting of $(u_i,0)$ and $(0,v_j)$.

If you assume $f$ is linear, then you can show that $\Gamma_f$ is the linear span of the vectors $(u_i, f(u_i)) \in U \times V$.

Conversely, assume that $\Gamma_f$ is a linear subspace. Then for any point $x \in \Gamma_f$, project onto the $U$ and $V$ parts and write it as $x = (u_x, v_x)$. Since it lies on a linear subspace, there is a linear map $T$ so that $v_x = T(u_x)$ for all $x$ on this subspace. But since it's on the graph, we also know that $v_x = f(u_x)$. So $f$ is the linear map $T$.